# Unable to purge efi-grub in live session

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I run Lubuntu 20.04 as the host OS for Virtualbox with legacy boot.  I tried to install Groovy in Virtualbox but I ran into this bug [Installation of Ubuntu Groovy with manual partitioning without an EFI System Partition fails on 'grub-install /dev/sda' even on non-UEFI systems](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1893964)
 - I got an error dialog saying

> Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error.

I figured I could purge `efi-grub` in live session then fix the boot loader over `chroot` after installation so I did not to have remove EFI file system the installer will create.

```
$ sudo apt purge grub-efi-amd64-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  localechooser-data
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  grub-efi-amd64-bin* grub-efi-amd64-signed* shim-signed* ubiquity*
  ubiquity-frontend-gtk*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  localechooser-data
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  shim-signed grub-efi-amd64-signed (due to shim-signed)
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 5 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,448 B of archives.
After this operation, 34.5 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?] 'Yes, do as I say!'
Abort.
```

How do I install the boot loader for my Groovy guest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found another way. I oversee in my question that ubiquity would also be gone.

Start live-session.

```
pkexec gparted
```

Create a MS-DOS partition and file system for `/` and others (maybe for `$HOME`) and format them. Start installation over desktop starter.

When it comes to create file system choose I thought it is called some thing else,
integrate your existing file system with the right mount points without formatting.

Ignore all warnings for EFI file system and proceed with the installation.  After installation (error pop up can not install GRUB to `/dev/sd*` (whatever your hard drive is named))

Ignore it.

Next step is important, do **not** quit live-session go back to it

and run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

Choose your hard drive and let GRUB install itself in MBR.

I saw no error. Remove installation media and start Ubuntu from the hard drive.