# EFI partition when installing on VirtualBox

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi

I'm trying to teach myself more about Linux and computers in general and so I was just installing Ubuntu 20.10 desktop as a VM running under VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host.

Usually in this situation I just let the Ubuntu installer configure the hard drives (which just creates a / partition formatted ext4). Today though I thought I'd create my own partitions so I created a new partition table and added a / and a swap partition (I realize swap isn't really needed any more).

When I went to apply the settings I was met with a very ominous sounding warning:

> No EFI System Partition was found. This system will likely not be able
> to boot successfully, and the installation process may fail. Please go
> back and add an EFI System Partition, or continue at your own risk.

I went back, ditched the settings I had and created a three partitions. An ESP (500MB), a / and a swap partition. When I tried to apply the settings this time I got the message:

> The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you
> to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition
> should be marked as a "Reserved BIOS boot area" and should be at least
> 1 MB in size. Note that this is not the same as a partition mounted on
> /boot.
>
> If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and correct this error,
> boot loader installation may fail later, although it may still be
> possible to install the boot loader to a partition.

I've done a bit of reading up on these error messages and after finding [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1886580) bug report I just hit enter on the warning about creating a BIOS boot area. Ubuntu installed fine and it boots fine as well.

I'm struggling to understand what is happening here. My gut feel is that the first warning message is being displayed when it isn't strictly needed. If this were a physical machine I can see that you'd pretty much always want an ESP, especially if you were going to make it a dual boot machine. I notice there's a setting in VirtualBox to "Enable EFI" I assume that makes it emulate UEFI based hardware. Without that option being checked though I assume VirtualBox emulates legacy BIOS.

When I run the command `ls /sys/firmware/efi` I get no output so I think the machine is using legacy boot but I'm not sure how to check that.

Thanks for any help, this isn't a problem that needs urgent attention I'm just trying to understand how this works.

Comment: A ESP partition is useless without UEFI

Comment: this is somekind a bug in ubiquity.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1893964

Comment: Thanks @nobody sounds like exactly the issue I'm seeing.

Comment: Maybe my a tittle bit confusing answer can help you. This way I could install groovy in bios-mode.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289017/unable-to-purge-efi-grub-in-live-session